# Do or For cycle to have more than ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a generic function:
`f[a_,b_]:=Module[{e,f,g,h}]`

which returns the scalar `g` and the list `h` in the form:
`{g,h}`.

Because of `RandomInteger` inside the `Module` block, I have several results for the same function `f[a_,b_]`.

My final aim is to have a `ListLinePlot` of the different (let's assume 10) `h` output lists on the same graphic.

Instead of launching:

```
f1=f[a,b];
f2=f[a,b];
f3=f[a,b];
...
f10=f[a,b];
```

and after that using:
`ListLinePlot[{f1[a,b][[2]],f2[a,b][[2]], ... f10[a,b][[2]]}]`

I was looking for something like:
`ListLinePlot[Table[f[a,b][i][[2]],{i,1,10}]`

even though there isn't any `i` dependence.

Any help?

Comment: Please provide a concrete minimal example which demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Bob, let's assume that my ```f[a,b]``` returns just ```h```, but ```h=RandomInteger[{1,100},1000]```. So, basically, I would like to iterate on a ```ListLinePlot``` the different ```h``` outputs.

Comment: With `h=RandomInteger[{1,100},1000]`, just `ListLinePlot[h]` or perhaps `Histogram[h]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ClearAll@f
f[a_, b_] := {a, RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10]}

ListLinePlot[Table[f[a, b][[2]], 10]]
```

Comment: Excatly what I meant, thank you Rohit!